# How do I show that a group G is the semidirect product of two cyclic subgroups, one of order p^2 and the other of order p?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, cyclic-groups, group-presentation, semidirect-product

> Let $p$ be an odd prime and $G$ be a group generated by elements $x,y$. Given $$x^{p^{2}}=1, x^{p} = y^{p}, yxy^{-1} = x^{p+1}, (yx^{-1})^{p} = 1,$$
> show that $G$ is the semidirect product of a two cyclic subgroups of order $p^{2}$ and $p$, respectively.

The given conditions imply that $|x| = p^{2}, |yx^{-1}|=p$. I think we can pick $x$ and $yx^{-1}$ to be the generator of $\mathbb{Z}/p^{2}\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, respectively. However, it isn't clear to me where this is leading. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The given conditions only tell you $x^{p^2}=1$, which means $|x|$ **divides** $p^2$; similar for $yx^{-1}$. You cannot just assert that this is their order, because you have not shown that the other relations do not affect what the order actually is.

Comment: An identical, now deleted, question [was posted by user ferris](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4048071/show-that-a-group-is-the-semidirect-product-of-two-cyclic-subgroups). Literally identical. Are you using two accounts to post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  Try to show that it is the split extension of $\Bbb Z_p$ by $\Bbb Z_{p^2}$ with the homomorphism $\varphi:\Bbb Z_p\hookrightarrow\Bbb Z_{p^2-p}\cong\rm{Aut}(\Bbb Z_{p^2})$ given by the inclusion.

Comment: For clarification, what do you mean by split extension?

Comment: I mean that $G\cong\Bbb Z_{p^2}\rtimes_\varphi\Bbb Z_p$.  In other words  that you have a semidirect product of the two cyclic groups.  The terminology comes from the fact that then there is a certain short exact sequence which splits.  Furthermore, there is a copy of $\Bbb Z_p$ in $G$, and it acts on $\Bbb Z_{p^2}$ by conjugation.